# CSS Transition Width Right to Left

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I am have made a heading (the word Welcome) that reveals itself once the page has loaded (`onload=""`).

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/olivermurfett/4bu7cw4s/) in case the code below doesn't work.

```js
function animate() {
  document.getElementById("mainText").style.width = "100%";

}
```

```css
#mainText {
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 100px;
  width: 0%;
  transition: width 2s;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip;
}
```

```html
<body onload="animate()">
  <h1 id="mainText">Welcome</h1>
</body>
```

The CSS and Plain JS work fine but I want the word "Welcome" to be revealed right side first and then moving along, so from the e to the W, instead of how it currently is, which opens left to right.

I have tried `text align: right;`, but this doesn't change anything.

I preferably don't want to use any jQuery, if the solution is a JS one.

An example of what the desired look should be, half way though the transition:

[image]

Comment: Yup... Done with the working fiddle... Try if that works out for you. Slightly hacky... ☺

Comment: probably this link will help u to achieve this http://jsfiddle.net/ZJyYY/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using Transitions and Positions:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  document.querySelector("h1").classList.add("active");
};
```

```css
h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
h1 .mask {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
h1.active .mask {
  right: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1><span class="mask"></span>Welcome</h1>
```

I just wrote an article about this - [CSS Transitions & JavaScript for Animated Entry Effects](https://blog.praveen.science/css-transitions-javascript-for-animated-entry-effects/). Hope it is useful... `:)`

Comment: Definitely not what I was asking, have a look at the Fiddle for an example

Comment: @OliverMurfett Yes I know... I am trying to do something... Let's see... It's kinda tough... `:)` But yeah, nice one...

Comment: @OliverMurfett I got one... Lemme add it now.

Comment: @OliverMurfett Refresh the answer and try?

Comment: That last one was exactly what I was looking for! Would you mind editing your comment and deleting the first 2 just to avoid confusion if people look at this in future?

Comment: @OliverMurfett I just blogged about this in [CSS Transitions & JavaScript for Animated Entry Effects](https://blog.praveen.science/css-transitions-javascript-for-animated-entry-effects/). Hope it is useful... `:)`

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) property to clip parts of the element so they are not visible. This property can also be animated to reveal the element again, using the `forwards` keyword in the animation so it stays in it's 'revealed' end state.

The `inset` takes values that are in order: from-top, from-right, from-bottom, from-left.

```css
#text {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 100px;
  animation: reveal 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes reveal {
  from {
    clip-path: inset(0 0 0 100%);
  }
  to {
    clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="text">Welcome</h1>
```

Comment: Does the forward keyword do anything? Can you please explain

Comment: @OliverMurfett Looks like he's using CSS keyframe animations.

Comment: @OliverMurfett It's an experimental technology, not supported by all browsers, you can have a look at it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

Comment: @OliverMurfett The `forwards` make the animation's last frame persist, or else the element reverts to its initial settings before the animation were applied

Comment: Sorry, I was busy so I didn't post an explanation yet. Will do later.

Comment: `forwards` is not really experimental, it's supported even by Internet Explorer.

Comment: What a elegant solution :)

Comment: Really great solution! same stuff I used for an Image it works.

Answer (score 4):

One option is `transform: translate` with a pseudo element, and no extra element needed.

```js
function animate() {
  document.getElementById("mainText").classList.add('show');
}
```

```css
#mainText {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: clip;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#mainText::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background: white;
  transition: transform 2s;
}
#mainText.show::after {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<body onload="animate()">

    <h1 id="mainText">Welcome</h1>
    
</body>
```

---

Another option, an even better solution, using the pseudo with `direction` and `left`/`width`.

This one work in the same way `clip-path` does, completely transparent against its background, as opposite to having a mask that revels the text, and with much better browser support.

```js
function animate() {
  document.getElementById("mainText").classList.add('show');
}
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
#mainText {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
#mainText::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  direction: rtl;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: left 2s, width 2s;
}
#mainText.show::before {
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body onload="animate()">

  <h1 id="mainText" data-text="Welcome">Welcome</h1>

</body>
```

Comment: This is a cool effect, but not actually what I was asking. I want the e, then the m, then the o ect. to be revealed in that order.

Comment: Have a look at the image I linked for what a screenshot half way though would look like.

Comment: @OliverMurfett Updated...no extra elements, simply CSS

Answer (score 3):

Something like this

```js
function animate() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.width = "0%";

}
```

```css
#mainText {
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip;
}
#overlay{
  width: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background:#fff;
  transition: width 2s;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<body onload="animate()">
  <h1 id="mainText">Welcome</h1>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will require a pseudo-element with a background on top of your heading serving as a mask. Instead of altering the inline styles I will simply add a class `is-active`. So everything style related can be styled via CSS.

```js
function animate() {
  document.getElementById("mainText").className = "is-active";
}
```

```css
#mainText {
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip;
}

#mainText:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  transition: width 2s;
}

#mainText.is-active:before {
  width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<body onload="animate()">
  <h1 id="mainText">Welcome</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Welp, Slightly too late

Answer (score 0):

I use `Transform: translateX` to achieve the desired effect.

It **slides** the text sideways or **horizontally** on the X axis.

```css
.message {
  color: darkred;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.sliding-text-1,
.sliding-text-2,
.sliding-text-3 {
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

.sliding-text-2 {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  color: darkblue;
}

.sliding-text-3 {
  animation-delay: 4s;
  color: darkgreen;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    transform: translateX(200px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="message sliding-text-1">Hello!</h1>
<h1 class="message sliding-text-2">Thanks for visiting!</h1>
<h1 class="message sliding-text-3">Have a nice day!</h1>
```